# I'm trying to make a multiple answer test and I keep coming up with the error of "list index out of range"

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a multiple choice test and I cannot figure out how/why one of my questions in out of range, I guess. I am new at coding and watching a video, I have 2 more questions than he does. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgQhwtIoQ7o

I've tried to take off some of the questions/answers.

```
questions = [Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
        Question(question_prompts[1], "b"),
        Question(question_prompts[2], "b"),
        Question(question_prompts[3], "d"),
        Question(question_prompts[4], "a")]


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hayes_kbosh1g/PycharmProjects/Giraffe/Ap.py", line 13, in <module>
    Question(question_promts[1], "b"),
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: This means `question_prompts` doesn't have 5 elements in it. You'll need a list of 5 elements to be able to do `question_prompts[4]`.

Answer (score 0):

This code will produce the same error:

```
question_prompts = [0]

questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "b"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "b"),
    Question(question_prompts[3], "d"),
    Question(question_prompts[4], "a"),
]
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-3d524ad6758c> in <module>
      7 questions = [
      8     Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
----> 9     Question(question_prompts[1], "b"),
     10     Question(question_prompts[2], "b"),
     11     Question(question_prompts[3], "d"),

IndexError: list index out of range
```

This code gives no error:

```
question_prompts = [0,1,2,3,4]

questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "b"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "b"),
    Question(question_prompts[3], "d"),
    Question(question_prompts[4], "a"),
]
```